# Elegant way to return a value inside an if

Tags: java, if-statement

Imagine you want to write a simple method, which take a String argument named "foo".  The method should return the int "1" if foo equals "toto" and "2" in the others cases. What is the best way to write this method without using a ternary expression ?

I have several solutions but can't decide by myself which one is the best in Java.

Solution 1 :

```
public int method1(String foo){
    if("toto".equals(foo)){
       return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Solution 2 :

```
public int method2(String foo){
    if("toto".equals(foo)){
       return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Solution 3 :

```
public int method3(String foo){
    int result = 2;
    if("toto".equals(foo)){
       result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Solution 4 :

```
public int method4(String foo){
    int result = 0;
    if("toto".equals(foo)){
       result = 1;
    } else {
       result = 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any other ideas?

Remember, I search a solution without ternary condition.

Thanks,

EDIT : I know that all the previous methods give the expected result, so all of them can be used. What I wanted to know and what wasn't clear in my initial question is : Is there some kind of standard in the Java community about this situation ? 
For example, I know there is a standard about the position of the brackets : you can put them a line after the if-statement but most of the people won't do it in Java.

I know that the ternary expression is probably the best here. But, as you can imagine, my "real" method is more complicated than that and can't used ternary. The problem I presented here is just a simplification, not the entire, real problem.

Comment: you eliminated the best option your-self , by saying `without using a ternary expression` in question

Comment: personally i would go with solution 1 as it nice and simple. But there are people who claims function should have only one return statement, and they will go with solution 3/4.

Comment: In short methods like this for me the first one is the best solution.

Comment: All those examples are missing parentheses

Comment: You should have probably asked this here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you can ask a question like this best on a forum (like reddit?). So you can see what people use most and why, as there isn't really 'one' answer for this (hence Q&A).

Comment: another possible solution is using `switch case`

Comment: Solution 4 should be `int result;` instead of `int result = 0;` this way the compiler will complain if it's not initialized before it's used which can be handy

Comment: @nickzoum I'm afraid hypothetical & example code are both Off-Topic for CodeReview. As are (most) X/Y questions.

Comment: @LanceJava you could take it even further `final int result`

Comment: @user902383 I cant stand the way people litter their code with final everywhere... i think it's just noise most of the time

Answer (score 2):

I think, the best is the most readable

```
 public int method(String foo){
   return "toto".equals(foo)?1:2;
 }
```

Comment: He excludes the ternary operator as an option.

Comment: this is not valid answer, first op wants solution WITHOUT ternary operator, and second we could argue is ternary operator is more readable than `if` statement. and by addition ternary operator does not scale, as soon as you add third option you need to use `if-else` statement anyway

Comment: @nickzoum it is shorter than solution 1 but it is not more readable

Comment: @user902383 in this cas there is not a third option : equals or not equals

Comment: fastest and better solution is the first of yours. Short if is not readable from starter programmers, and also isn't easy to debug if you use more than 1 function whit this method